# List symbols exported by an assembly that are used by another assembly

Tags: .net, utilities

I have two .net assemblies - lets call them A and B. Assembly A uses some classes exported by B.

Is there a utility that can tell me which of B's classes are used by A and which members (functions, properties, etc) of those classes are used?

I've tried reflector, JetBrains dotPeek, NDepend, and Just Decompile but (unless I'm missing something) they only seem to show assembly-level dependencies. Any suggestions for what I can try?

EDIT: Added NDepend, and Just Decompile, and clarified that I'm not interested in assembly-level dependencies

Answer (score 1):

This is the sort of thing that I believe [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) will let you find out easily. I still (to my shame) haven't tried it out, but this problem sounds like NDepend's bread and butter.

(If you *can't* do it at the moment with NDepend, I suspect the author would welcome a feature request...)

Comment: Thanks Jon. I tried ndepend but it only seems to report on assembly-level dependencies.

Comment: @AndyJohnson: Can you not ask it for each method / type, which other types are used? And then filter those?

Comment: @JonI'd have to re-install it to check, but the problem is that there are a lot of exported classes. I was hoping for something that would do a pass over them all and list only the methods that are used by the dependent assembly.

Answer (score 1):

You also might want to try [Teleriks Just Decompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx?utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=sm&utm_campaign=ad) (free download so may give you want you want)

Comment: Thanks @KOL. It lets me find where a given symbol is used, but there doesn't seem to be a way to to this for all exported symbols without clicking each one individually. Thanks for the pointer though, I'll keep it installed.